# emulator testing vs Cloud based testing

Tags: android, ios, testing, mobile, cloud

we are developing a hybrid application. We are testing very well with chrome browser
tools. Now the question is we need to do more functional testing. So do we need to use emulator testing or cloud based like perfecto, Mobile Labs, Device anywhere?
In emulators maximum functionalities had been tested and we have couple of device to ensure the functionality again. What is the exact use case we have to go for Cloud based testing. Because in both of it UAT is not possible.More over some times cloud solution is getting slow because of internet connectivity. From Testing perspective we are not sure whether the delay is because of app services call or internet delay.

If some one can help us in identifying exactly which scenario we should use Cloud Testing and which scenario we should use Emulator testing?

Is there difference exists among them except Hardware?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yep, lots of differences in software. First of all, it is not running on real hardware (it is running on x86-based PC that is not ARM), there is no real WiFi, memory or display components, and software is typically some sort of vanilla and does not contain any OEM software (skinnings, customizations etc.)

Pretty good check list can be found [here](http://testdroid.com/news/rely-only-on-real-emulators-vs-devices).